# How to invite my self to test flight?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I have created `.ipa`  , and i have a `test flight` account, and everything is set up.
I have downloaded the `test flight` app to my `iPad` .
I would like to send invitation to **my self**, so i can check the `.ipa` in my own iPad .

When i am trying to invite my self(with my email) in `test flight` site, they say i already a member.(right, thats me)
When i open the app in my iPad, i see blank page says "i have to get invitation and approve it" .

So, how can i check my own build in my iPad ?

Comment: are the AppleIDs the same on your device (iPad) and you are using for your Developer Program?

Comment: no. in my device there is an apple id with email x , than with that same email x i registered to test flight, and the build is under email y- which is the developer account .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to register the device, open browser from the iPad, log in with my account to test flight, and it than installs the app to my iPad .

Comment: how and where did you "register the device"? to the icloud?

Comment: perhaps its not working for me because i was using chrome browser and not safari?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps I do,

(1) We can send invitation through [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com)

(2) If you are working for a company, you must have access as an "app manager" or higher, if not request your team member whose role is app manager.

(3) After selecting your apps, choose TestFlight[image]

(4) Then choose "App Store Connect Users" under "Internal Groups " on left menu.

(5)Then you can "+" button where you can choose the ID to send invitation.

[image]

(6) Test flight invitation will describe how to install the app in mobile.